# The nuance of 得る compared with ~ば

Tags: grammar, nuances

## Japanese

以下の文を比較すると、

> でき得るならば、独立して事業を始めたい。
>
> できれば、独立して事業を始めたい。

意味が同じですか？どう違いますか？すみませんが、説明して頂けませんか？

## English

If we compare the following two sentences:

> でき得るならば、独立して事業を始めたい。
>
> できれば、独立して事業を始めたい。

Is the meaning the same? How do they differ? Could someone explain it?

Comment: こんな意見もあります -> http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1113809046

Answer (score 4):

The `～得る` construction already implies possibility, so `でき得る` sounds redundant to me, like "if it's possible to be possible" (unless you were using できる to mean that something is finished, but your examples aren't).

Another possibility would be `～ものなら` to indicate that achieving what you want might be difficult.

> - できれば、独立して事業を始めたい。　→　Just a regular "if I can"
> - できるものなら、……　→　"If I *really* could (but I think it would improbable), ..."

Comment: Your answer is on the right track. What you are trying to say is indicative conditional vs. counterfactual conditional.

Comment: `でき得る sounds redundant... unless you were using できる to mean that something is finished` でも、辞書にはこんな例が。「 **できうる**かぎりの努力」([デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/21083/meaning/m0u/))

Answer (score 1):

はい。同じ意味です。でも、"できれば、独立して事業を始めたい"　はもっといいと思います。

Comment: Yeah the meanings are same, and I also think the latter is more common and natural. The former sounds a bit too formal, and gives an impression that there is a lesser hope or the speaker is just humble.

Answer (score 0):

Almost same meaning but でき得るものならば one shows lower chance, close 0, of achieving the goal. So I think でき得るものならば frequently used with past tence, for example, でき得るものならば、独立して事業を始めたかった. So in this way, he wanted to start his own business but it is too late.